# Maven customization with settings.xml

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to set up some command line Maven parameters in `settings.xml`.
For example, -T (--threads) `settings.xml` representation is 'maven.artifact.threads'.
But for `-q` (`--quiet`) and `-b` (`--builder`) I can't find last one.

How to set up `-q` and `-b` with `settings.xml` ?

Comment: CLI option `-T` and the system property `maven.artifact.threads` aren't the same. The former is used to perform parallel builds while the latter is used to download artifacts in parallel.

Comment: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: khmarbaise, maven 3.3.9